# Очистка бэкстека при запуска нового активити

Tags: java, android, android-studio, activity, android-intent

При запуске приложение я попадаю на активити "А", где юзер проходит что-то а-ля авторизации. В `onCreate` методе "А" я проверяю, есть ли данные об авторизации и если есть, сразу запускаю активити "B". Проблема в том, что в обоих случаях я могу вернуться обратно к "А" нажав кнопку "назад".

Как сделать так, чтобы при запуске "В" кнопка "назад" возвращала на рабочий стол, а не обратно к "А".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего вам нужно лишь добавить

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

в тег активити `A` в манифест.